# Trying to do some delete with the function destroy said Error:Missing required parameters for Route Laravel 6.0 how can i fix it

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***Trying to use `destroy function()` said the error above i dont know how to fix it, i tried to delete some field of my database from my aplication***

- Below i will let the code of my `index function()`,`destroy function()`, route and also the html where i tried to invocate de function

***Route***

```php
Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados', 'miembroController');
```

***`Index function()`***

```php
public function index(Request $request, $id_evento,$id_miembro){
        $miembros = DB::select(DB::raw(
            "SELECT id_miembro, razon_social, denominacion_comercial, web,
                    rif
            FROM miembro
           " ));

        return view ('home.miembro')->with('miembros', $miembros)->with('id_evento', $id_evento)->with('id_miembro', $id_miembro);
    }
```

***`Destroy function()`***

```php
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        $miembro=Miembro::find($id);
        $miembro->delete();
        return back()->with('Evento eliminado');
    }
```

*** Html code where i try to use the `destroy function()`***

```html
                <td>
                     <form action={{ route('asociados.destroy', ['asociados' => $item->id_miembro]) }} method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                  </form>
                </td>
```

***All routes***

```php
Route::resource('/eventos', 'EventoController');

Route::resource('/detalle', 'DetalleController');

Route::resource('/entradas', 'EntradaController');

Route::resource('/eventos/{evento}/entradas', 'EntradaController');

//Route::resource('/horario', 'HorarioController');
//Route::resource('/eventos/{evento}/horarios', 'HorarioeventoController');
Route::resource('/eventos/{evento}/horarios/{eventos}/funciona', 'HorarioController');

Route::resource('/eventos/{evento}/horarios/{horario}/hola', 'HorarioeventoController');

//Route::resource('/miembros', 'MiembroController');

Route::delete('/miembros/{id}', 'miembroController@destroy')->name('miembrosDestroy'); //-----ver----

Route::resource('/contactos', 'Persona_de_contactoController');

Route::resource('/miembros/{miembros}/contactos', 'Persona_de_contactoController');

Route::resource('/miembros/{miembros}/telefonos', 'TelefonoController');

Route::resource('/correos/{correo}/miembros', 'CorreoController');

Route::resource('/miembros/{miembros}/correos', 'CorreoController');

Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados', 'miembroController');

Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/miembroevento', 'Miembro_eventoController');

Route::resource('/tipoCerveza', 'Tipo_cervezaController');

Route::resource('/cervezas/{cervezas}/tipos', 'CervezaController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
//you have the `resource` 
Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados', 'miembroController');
```

And this `/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados` is the shape of your uri.

for `destroy` you also need to provide all the necessary data both `{eventos}` and `{miembros}`.(which are `eventos` id and `miembros` id) like your `index`. rather than just `$id`.

or you can add another one, if you do not want to change the destroy function.

```php
Route::resource('/eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados', 'miembroController');

Route::delete('/miembros/{id}', 'miembroController@destroy')->name('miembrosDestroy');
```

if you took this approach, you also need to change the html form action.

I updated the route as named route, for in your form

```html
action={{ route('miembrosDestroy', ['id' => $item->id_miembro]) }}
```

Comment: Sorry but now how could be the form action ?

Comment: @Rinzler21 I updated my answer, this should work. I think.

Comment: Said the following error `The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.`

Comment: @Rinzler21, maybe you have a similar route, can you put `Route::delete('/miembros/{id}', 'miembroController@destroy')->name('miembrosDestroy');` at very top of the file? and try again?

Comment: @Rinzler21 or can you share your routes file?

Comment: See the post again i put all the routes

Comment: @Rinzler21 can you please run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal?

Comment: Yes and says that the route of miembroController destroy is this `eventos/{eventos}/miembros/{miembros}/asociados/{asociado}`

Comment: @Rinzler21 there is no delete method that we just added? not showing?

Comment: No that is the only one

Answer (score 0):

You cant try this

```
public function destroy($id)
  { 
    $miembro = Miembro::destroy($id);
    return back()->with('Evento eliminado');
  }
```